# Artifacts when watching videos online

Tags: video, video-streaming, visual-artifacts, distortion

A couple of months ago, artifacts started appearing when watching videos on YouTube and other online platforms.  They look like color distortions in bright areas (See examples). When I switch to full screen mode, the artifacts disappear, as well as when I try to take a screenshot.

I tried updating video driver, codecs, but the problem persists. There is no problem when watching offline videos with MPC.
What can the problem be related to?

Machine:  Asus ZenBook UM535Q Win 11

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

2nd example full screen mode:

[image: Example 2 full screen mode]

Comment: Don't know enough about it to offer suggestions, but I expect this is an HDR-display-related compatibility problem

Comment: It appears that not enough bits are used. There are settings for video quality in YouTube; choose a higher quality and/or different format.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. The HDR mode was on, but it was automatically turned off when the battery was running. Then I saw color distortions in the video. Apparently, there is some bug and the HDR was not turning off completely automatically when on battery power. After I turned off the HDR manually everything was fine.